# Timezone getting removed in python flask

Tags: python, flask, pytz

After a user logs in, I am setting a session variable to the time with utc.. but the timezone is getting stripped.

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
utc = timezone('utc')
session['login_time'] = datetime.datetime.now(utc)
```

When I print after the assignment the timezone is there `2021-06-11 23:56:00.161971+00:00`.  And a decorator function gets called. When I print `session['login_time']` the timezone is removed.  `2021-06-11 23:56:00`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I will use `.strftime` to help format the datetime and `%Z` is to show the timezone.

You can see the [strftime document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to help you format the time. I will use this code to replace your original one:

```
session['login_time'] = datetime.datetime.now(utc).strftime('"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z"')
login_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(session['login_time'],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z" )
utct = utc.localize(login_time)
print(utct)
print(type(utct))
```

And here is the output:

```
2021-06-12 01:00:23+00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: This makes it a string type.  I was hoping to keep it as a time object. I was doing some calculations with the time differences.

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can see whether this one is ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-add the `timezone('utc')` when i needed to use the time in another function.

```
def diff_min(t):
    utc = timezone('utc')
    t = utc.localize(t)
```